# generate json format using php

Tags: php, json

I want to generate .json file format in php file. for that i write following code.

```
<?php
$res=array();
$response = array();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con){
die("connection failed".mysql_error());
}
$db=mysql_select_db("companies",$con);
if(!$db){
die("connection failed".mysql_error());
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM companies");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
 $res[]=array('name'=> $row['name'],'id' => $row['company_id']+1);
}
mysql_close($con);
$response['company'] = $res;
echo (json_encode($response));
?>
```

it gives output like this:

```
{"company":[{"name":"abc","id":2},{"name":"cde","id":3}]}
```

but i want output like this:

```
[{"company":{"name":"abc","id":1}},{"company":{"name":"cde","id":2}}]
```

how should i change my php file?

Comment: for what purpose you want the above output??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more associative array:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
    $res[] = array(
        'company' => array('name'=> $row['name'],'id' => $row['company_id']+1) 
    );
}
```

And now all you have to send is json encoded `$res`.

Comment: Thanx for answer, when i look "http://localhost/project/companies.json" in my browser it show the data. but i want to hide the data. can i do it?  if yes, how ?

Comment: if you are using this data in javascript and getting it by AJAX request, then you can not hide it.

Comment: Thanx. no I'm try to access these data from Ruby file. can i hide these data?